# Access Grid inside GridView to manipulate its width programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp

```
    <GridView x:Name="MainGridView">
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:SomeViewModel">
                <Grid x:Name="I_NEED_THIS">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="180*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock with some binding/>
                    <TextBlock with some binding/>
                    <TextBlock with some binding/>
                    <TextBlock with some binding/>
                    <TextBlock with some binding/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

I need access to each Grid (x:Name="I_NEED_THIS") at runtime to manipulate some grid parameters at runtime. How I can run over each grid that was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, you have to walk the Visual Tree and find the element that you want to make changes too. This blog article should get you started:

http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html

Comment: If not necessary, I will not suggest to `VisualTreeHelper`. Welcome to use Data Binding.

Comment: If you need to modify grid parameters, it would be hard to pull off in data biding. You could use an item template selector as well, but that only applies if you have expected conditions. If you need to access it in pure code behind, the visual tree is basically the only way.

Comment: I don't know how would it be hard to pull of in data binding, and in this scenario it is not the only way in pure code behind. You can use `ContainerFromItem` to get the `GridViewItem`, then use `ContentTemplateRoot` to get the `Grid`. It's not a big deal friend, of course `VisualTreeHelper` works, I just think we can find other way to do this work?

Comment: If we had more context about what needed to be changed and why, I'm sure we could have a more direct answer. Without that, any of the ones discussed are optio s